# Alan Storm's tutorial on Layoutviewer (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am using Magento version 1.3.2.1. I have installed configuration viewer, but can not get Layoutview to work.  Magento will not load. getting a 500 internal Server error. I have copied the code from his website.
Derectory tree:

```
Magentotutorial
  Configviewer
     subdirectory
  Layoutviewer
     subdirectorys
```

I copied the configviewer.xml, only changing the name to layoutviewer.xml

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Ah, that would be Alan Storm :)

Answer (score 8):

which configviewer.xml are you talking about? `app\etc\modules\alanstormdotcom_configviewer.xml`? If you've copied that, you need to edit the contents of it so that it looks like:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Layoutviewer>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Layoutviewer>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: @Jacqueline - you're welcome, you should accept the answer (click the tick) if it worked for you.