# Magento Layoutviewer (Alan Storm) not working after installation

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento version: 1.9.2.4

I am currently working through this tutorial, and am trying to install the Layoutviewer module.

I following the link on the page to where I could get the layout viewer, and then used the manual install guide on [this](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2012/08/installing-alan-storms-layoutviewer-in-magento-works-with-1-7/) page to install it.

The module is being detected by magento, and is listed on the `Disable Modules Output` section (it is enabled).

The directory tree for the module is as follows:

```
magento1
    app
        code
            local
                Magentotutorial
                    Layoutviewer
```

I have also made sure that the config file's name and contents are 100% correct.

When I try to use the module (`http://127.0.0.1/magento1/helloworld/index/index/?showLayout=page`) it doesn't work, and just shows me the screen as it was before.

Is there anything I could be missing, or did I perhaps install the module incorrectly?

***edit***

*I have already found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824671/alan-storms-tutorial-on-layoutviewer-magento) that is basically identical to mine, but it's very old so I don't want to comment on in - it did not help me solve the problem.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alan Storm's tutorial on Layoutviewer (Magento)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824671/alan-storms-tutorial-on-layoutviewer-magento)

Comment: Please see the **edit** portion of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved:

I placed the Layoutviewer in the Magentotutorial directory, but it was supposed to be in it's own (`Alanstormdotcom`) directory.

Both of these solutions worked:

- Move the module to the correct directory or
- Replace all references to Alanstormdotcom/alanstormdotcom to Magentotutorial/magentotutorial

Answer (score 0):

Found this Googling for the same problem. My problem was that I put Storm's module in `/community/Alanstormdotcom/`. It won't work from there, it must be in *local* (`/local/Alanstormdotcom/`).